# How to make model.ImageField as mandatory in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-media

I need to make upload image in django admin panel as a mandatory field, is there any possibility?

Here what i did:

**models.py**

```
class ContentData(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True) 
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads", blank=True) 
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default = 1,
                                   blank = True,
                                    null = True,
                                    help_text ='1->Active, 0->Inactive', 
                                    choices =(
                                    (1, 'Active'), (0, 'Inactive')
                                    ))
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just removed

> blank=True

in the imageField.